# How to implement a flexbox layout with aria-friendly arrow-based keyboard shortcuts

Tags: css, flexbox, accessibility, wai-aria

For accessibility purposes, when using a grid for presentation (e.g. YouTube.com's homepage; as opposed to using it for tabular data) a `role` of `grid` and `gridcell` are applied to the collection and individual items, respectively([1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#grid)).

In addition, aria specifies that the grid should be able to be navigated with arrow-based keyboard shortcuts ([2](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#grid)). All the examples they give have the cell coordinates embedded within the actual html ([3](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/grid/LayoutGrids.html)).

However, if a developer is using flexbox to handle the actual layout (e.g. [4](https://codepen.io/aaronkahlhamer/pen/mAqVPB)) then the html doesn't include the row:column address of each cell.  Without these coordinates, how does one implement a flexbox layout that also supports aria-friendly arrow-based keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: I've pondered this a long time and still have not found an answer. Lighthouse will complain that you lack the required children for the grid role if you don't add rows, but with css-grid you don't need to define separate rows. I agree it's unclear how to semantically do this.